# How to properly format JSON for storing a time/temperature combination

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm collecting temperature data with their timestamps, and looking to store the data as it's collected in Firebase.

So for example, I'd have something like:

10/04/2017 12:05:22 - 84 degrees

10/04/2017 12:05:27 - 85 degrees

etc.

Is it possible to structure my Firebase input in such a way that lends itself to formatting in a good way to store the time information as well as the temperature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about separate fields for the time, and temperature, and possibly units?

```
{
  "timestamp": 1507173014643,
  "temperature": 64,
  "unit": "Fahrenheit"
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Would you know how to format the Firebase input in such a way that each entry looks like that?

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, I figured it out. Your format works well, thank you!